# How to remove part of filename using vbscript

Tags: vbscript

I have hundreds of filenames with a - (dash) 0 (zero) like V-45X-0892-0.pdf, V-45X-0893-0.pdf and would like to strip the -0 from filename.

Here's what I have but is not working.

```
folderspec = "C:\Dave\"
strRename = ""

Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set f = fs.GetFolder(folderspec)

For Each f1 In f.Files
    Filename = folderspec & f1.Name
    NewFilename = Replace(Filename, "%-0.pdf""%.pdf", strRename)
    fs.MoveFile Filename, NewFilename
Next

MsgBox "All Done"
```

Comment: "it's not working" is pretty vague. How did you come up with the second parameter in the replace function. There are some good tutorials on how to use the function. https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/replace_vba.php

Comment: `Replace(Filename, "%-0.pdf""%.pdf", strRename)` -> `Replace(Filename, "-0.pdf", ".pdf")`

Comment: Thank you Jeremy and Ansgar, I appreciate it,

Answer (score 1):

Here's code based on your Question with modifications made to the `For Each` loop. Note that you don't need to use `MoveFile`, you can simply update the file's `Name` property directly:

```
Dim objFSO
Dim objFolder
Dim objFile
Dim sFolderSpec

sFolderSpec = "C:\Dave\"

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(sFolderSpec)

For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
    If InStr(objFile.Name, "-0") > 0 Then objFile.Name = Replace(objFile.Name, "-0", "")
Next

MsgBox "All Done"
```